# How to plot (x,y) values in matplotlib on an existing plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am currently trying to identify peaks on a randomly generated plot that I have created.

My code is as follows:

```
x_range = np.arange(0,100,0.5) #my x values
for i in len(ys): #ys is my range of y values on the chart
    for j in range(start,len(ys)): #Brute forcing peak detection
        temp.append(ys[j])
        check = int(classtest.isPeak(temp)[0])
        if check == 1:
            xval = temp.index(max(temp)) #getting the index
            xlist = x_range.tolist()
            plt.plot(xlist[xval],max(temp),"ro") 
    start =  start + 1
    temp = []
```

However when plotting the values on the graph, it seems to plot the correct y position, but not x. Here is an example of what is happening:
[image: As you can see, the x values are going crazy!]

I am really not sure what is causing this problem, and I would love some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `temp` is getting shorter and shorter as `start` increases.
So the index, `xval`, corresponding to a max in `temp` is not in itself the correct index into `x_range`. Rather, you have to increase `xval` by `start` to find the corresponding index in `x_range`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 100
ys = (np.random.random(N)-0.5).cumsum()
xs = np.linspace(0, 100, len(ys))

plt.plot(xs, ys)
start = 0
temp = []
for i in range(len(ys)): #ys is my range of y values on the chart
    for j in range(start,len(ys)): #Brute forcing peak detection
        temp.append(ys[j])
        xval = temp.index(max(temp)) #getting the index
        plt.plot(xs[xval+start], max(temp),"ro") 
    start =  start + 1
    temp = []
plt.show()
```

[image]

While that does manage to place the red dots at points on the graph, as you can
see the algorithm is placing a dot at *every* point on the graph, not just at local
maxima. Part of the problem is that when `temp` contains only one point, it is
of course the max. And the double for-loop ensures that every point gets
considered, so at some point `temp` contains each point on the graph alone as a
single point.

A different algorithm is required. A local max can be identified as any
point which is bigger than its neighbors:

```
ys[i-1] <= ys[i] >= ys[i+1]
```

therefore, you could use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 100
ys = (np.random.random(N)-0.5).cumsum()
xs = np.linspace(0, 100, len(ys))

plt.plot(xs, ys)
idx = []
for i in range(1, len(ys)-1):
    if ys[i-1] <= ys[i] >= ys[i+1]:
        idx.append(i)
plt.plot(xs[idx], ys[idx], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that [`scipy.signal.argrelextrema`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) or [`scipy.signal.argrelmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html)  can also be used to find local maximums:

```
from scipy import signal
idx = signal.argrelextrema(ys, np.greater)
plt.plot(xs[idx], ys[idx], 'ro')
```

produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only problem now is I am getting the error:

plt.plot(x_range[idx], ys[idx], 'ro')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list